# Customize ticks with and without labels in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, yaxis

How can I remove the labelling but not the ticks from the non-integers, i.e. 4.5, 5.5, 6.5 …, but keep both the labelling and the ticks on the integers, i.e. 4, 5, 6 …, in the example below?

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", facet_col="species")

fig.update_yaxes(linewidth=0.5,
                ticks="outside", tickwidth=0.5, tickcolor='blue', ticklen=10, dtick=0.5,
                tickfont_size=22, 
                )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You just need to set the value of `dtick=0.5` to `dtick=1.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build arrays for **tickvals** and **ticktext**

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", facet_col="species")

fig.update_yaxes(linewidth=0.5,
                ticks="outside", tickwidth=0.5, tickcolor='blue', ticklen=10, dtick=0.5,
                tickfont_size=22, 
                )

la = int(df["sepal_length"].min())
lm = int(df["sepal_length"].max().round(0))
ticks = np.arange((lm - la) * 2) * 0.5 + la
fig.update_yaxes(
    tickmode="array",
    tickvals=ticks,
    ticktext=np.where(ticks.astype(int) == ticks, ticks, " "),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What am I doing wrong? ---- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-4b68f40b9077> in <module>
      7 
      8 la = int(df["sepal_length"].min())
----> 9 lm = int(df["sepal_length"].max().round(0))
     10 ticks = np.arange((lm - la) * 2) * 0.5 + la
     11 fig.update_yaxes(

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'round'

Comment: I suspect you were running before `df` was defined.  I've updated code example to be MWE

Comment: That works! Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just ran the code on another machine and had again problem with the `round` attribute. However, changing `lm = int(df["sepal_length"].max().round(0)` to `lm = 'int(df["sepal_length"].round(0).max())` made a difference.